# Changed my website to SSL but http site appears on google

Tags: ssl

I recently updated my website from http to https, when I goto search for my website on google the http one shows up....How do I change that? Do I need to contact google?

Answer (score 1):

No just set up a 301 redirect so all requests on HTTP go to HTTPS

This can be done in Apache using the Rewrite module.

See this link: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS

This has a number of advantages, it means you will maintain your previous SEO ranking for the new pages, also any one typing in addresses directly will go to your HTTPS site and Google will eventually change to show the HTTPS one.

Comment: That is assuming that he is using Apache

Comment: Correct that is assuming he is using Apache

Comment: I have an htacess file do I just put that fix in that?

Comment: I added those lines to my htacess file and got this error when I goto my page `Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.`

Comment: Here is my htacess code: `# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a 301 redirect from the http site to the https one and Google will update gradually.

Alternatively you can ask Google http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=164734

Answer (score 0):

google isn't really looking at the port - which is http (port 80) or https (port 443). you need to setup a redirect in your server config file or htaccess file that sends all requests to port 443. You can do it programmatically as well, but it's less efficient.